# Making a normal method generic

Tags: c#

I have the following method with which I have some difficulties in making it generic.

```
private void AddCheckBox(CheckBox cb, Expression<Func<ISomeInterface, bool>> func)
{
    var memRef = MemberReference.Create(mSomeInterfaceAttribute, func);
    .......
}
```

The definition for `MemberReference.Create` is:

```
public static MemberReference<K, M> Create<K, M>(K obj, Expression<Func<K, M>> func) where K : class;
```

This is what I tried:

```
private void AddCheckBox<T>(CheckBox cb, Expression<Func<T, bool>> func)
{
    var memRef = MemberReference.Create<T, bool>(mSomeInterfaceAttribute, func);
    ......
}
```

I am getting invalid arguments errors:

> Error  2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'
>
> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'MemberReference.Create(ISomeInterafce, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: And what didn't work? Compiler errors?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question, I am getting invalid arguments error

Comment: K has the requirement class so T must too `private void AddCheckBox<T>(CheckBox cb, Expression<Func<T, bool>> func)
 where T : class`

Comment: Which argumnet? Don't be shy about posting the _full_ error .

Comment: Make sure that `mSomeInterfaceAttribute` is of type `T`.

Comment: I have added the errors. where T: class for method AddCheckBox didn't fixed the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need to do is to change your generic definition to

```
private void AddCheckBox<T>(CheckBox cb, Expression<Func<T, bool>> func) where T : class
{
    var memRef = MemberReference.Create<T, bool>(mSomeInterfaceAttribute as T, func);
    (....)
}
```

Note the `where T : class` at the end of the definition and the `as T` in the call to `Create`.

Comment: Yeah, it works, but what if instead of T inside the method I wanna use an interface. I want something like: if(T is Interface1) Craete<Interface1, bool>(m as Interafce1) else if(T is Interface2) Create<Interface2, bool>(m as Interface2). Hope I make myself clear and sorry for not mentioning this from the beginning.

Comment: Or I can leave this code, but I also have a dictionary that I need to add the type T to it, but I need to I don't know , cast it to my type (ISomeInterface)

Comment: You could just as well specify a second type in the definition and use that. Something along the lines of `AddCheckBox<T,K>` and then write `MemberReference<K, bool>.Create(mSomeInterfaceAttrinute as T, func)`. You'd probably need to add the same `where` clause for the new type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your definition

```
MemberReference<K, M> Create<K, M>(K obj, Expression<Func<K, M>> func) where K : class
```

Firstly there is the requirement that `K` is a class, so this means that your `addcheckbox` method must also declare `T : class`

Secondly where does `mSomeInterfaceAttribute` come from, it needs to be defined as type T?

Assuming you've declare this as a class field you will need to make the class rather than the method generic.

eg.

```
class MyClass<T> where T: class
{

   private T mSomeInterfaceAttribute;

   private void AddCheckBox(CheckBox cb, Expression<Func<T, bool>> func)
   {
      var memRef = MemberReference.Create<T, bool>(mSomeInterfaceAttribute, func);
      ......
   }
}
```

Additional you wouldn't need to specify the type parameters to MemberReference.Create because they could then me inferred.  Allowing you to just do

```
class MyClass<T> where T: class
{

   private T mSomeInterfaceAttribute;

   private void AddCheckBox(CheckBox cb, Expression<Func<T, bool>> func)
   {
      var memRef = MemberReference.Create(mSomeInterfaceAttribute, func);
      ......
   }
}
```

Comment: I changed the method to this: private void AddCheckBox<T>(CheckBox cb, Expression<Func<T, bool>> func) where T: class. Still getting the same errors

Comment: @vBx Updated the answer but you need to explain where `mSomeInterfaceAttribute` came from.

Answer (score 1):

Given this:

```
public class MemberReference<K, M>
{
    public static MemberReference<K, M> Create<K, M>(K obj, Expression<Func<K, M>> func) where K : class
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then the following shoud work:

```
private static void AddCheckBox<T>(CheckBox cb, Expression<Func<T, bool>> func) where T : class
{
    var Tvar = (T) mSomeInterfaceAttribute; // Hopefully it is of this type, make that sure
    var memRef = MemberReference<T, bool>.Create(Tvar, func);
}
```